# Difference between npm t and npm run test

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I've seen some people use the command `npm t` when running tests. Is this command any different to running `npm run test`?

Comment: `npm help t` 3 more to go...

Comment: @AndyRay Cheers, that is trippy!

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR there is no difference.

It's just a shortcut for `npm test` which run the test command in the `package.json` file. `npm run test` performs the same action in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Following on from Andy Ray's comment, the documentation states that `t` is an alias for `test`.

```
npm help t
```