# Jest tests pass locally, but fail on bitbucket pipeline

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, bitbucket-pipelines

I have errors that I make in code:

```
export class UnprocessableException extends Error {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(responseStatus.UNPROCESSABLE, message);
    }
}
```

I then test them in jest tests like:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (e) {
    expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(UnprocessableException);
}
```

This passes/works locally, but on Bitbucket the tests fail with the same commands. The tests all say:

```
Expected: UnprocessableException 

Received: Error
```

Any idea why jest and bitbucket types don't seem to like each other?

Comment: Note that your text still passes if the code in the try _doesn't_ throw an error. Use [`toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) (with [`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects) if you're testing a promise).

Answer (score 0):

Of course I get it working right after I post the question. So changing

```
- npm run build
- npm run test
```

to

```
- npm test
- npm run build
```

Fixed it.
The build command just builds webpack, so I don't think it was the order. But not having "run" seems to fix the issue. Not sure how as npm run test also works on my local machine.

Comment: Not sure why there is a difference though, would be interested in theories. I came here  because my testing running locally, but failing inconsistently in the pipeline, but did a wee search and the "npm test" and "npm run test" (and npm t) should be the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031559/difference-between-npm-t-and-npm-run-test

Wondering if it might be the order, and something is happening the build process that changes the files that the test is using in some way?